# Error Running node server , webpack for React configuration

Tags: django, reactjs, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

Ive been digging into this for last long few hours and cant catch the bug. Im following the ["Guide on how to create and set up your Django project with webpack, npm and ReactJS :)"](https://gist.github.com/juanto85/826426f9bc7bef44c872f4df39d57c3c)

this is the error I get when I try:
`node server.js`

```
(bonchans) ➜  bonchans git:(master) ✗ node server.js                                                 

    /Users/JuanPerez/Desktop/Sandbox/DEV/django+reactjs/django-react-boilerplate/bonchans/bonchans/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:19
    throw new WebpackOptionsValidationError(webpackOptionsValidationErrors);
    ^

    WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has 
    been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
     - configuration.resolve has an unknown property 'modulesDirectories'. These 
    properties are valid:
       object { alias?, aliasFields?, cachePredicate?, cacheWithContext?, 
    descriptionFiles?, enforceExtension?, enforceModuleExtension?, extensions?, 
    fileSystem?, mainFields?, mainFiles?, moduleExtensions?, modules?, plugins?, 
    resolver?, symlinks?, unsafeCache?, useSyncFileSystemCalls? }
     - configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty.
        at webpack (/Users/JuanPerez/Desktop/Sandbox/DEV/django+reactjs/django-react-boilerplate/bonchans/bonchans/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:19:9)
        at Object.<anonymous> 
    (/Users/JuanPerez/Desktop/Sandbox/DEV/django+reactjs/django-react-
   boilerplate/bonchans/bonchans/server.js:5:22)
        at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
        at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
        at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
        at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
   (bonchans) ➜  bonchans git:(master) ✗
```

### Configuration files:

---

#### my `package.json` looks like this:

```
    {
      "name": "bonchans",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",

      "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/juanto85/bonchans.git"
      },
      "author": "Juan Perez",
      "license": "ISC",
      "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/juanto85/bonchans/issues"
      },
      "homepage": "https://github.com/juanto85/bonchans#readme",
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
        "react": "^15.6.1",
        "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
        "webpack": "^3.5.5",
        "webpack-bundle-tracker": "^0.2.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1"
      }
      "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --progress --colors",
        "build-production": "webpack --config webpack.prod.config.js --progress --colors",
        "watch": "node server.js"
        }
    }
```

#### My `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```
var path = require("path")
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')


module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: [
      'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      './apps/static/js/index'
  ],

  output: {
      path: path.resolve('./apps/static/bundles/'),
      filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
      publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/static/bundles/', // Tell django to use this URL to load packages and not use STATIC_URL + bundle_name
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(), // don't reload if there is an error
    new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [
      // we pass the output from babel loader to react-hot loader
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'], },
    ],
  },

  resolve: {


modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'bower_components'],
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
      }
    }
```

#### `server.js` looks like this:

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server')
var config = require('./webpack.config')

new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  hot: true,
  inline: true,
  historyApiFallback: true
}).listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }

  console.log('Listening at 0.0.0.0:3000')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

From `package.json` I can see that you're using webpack v3, but the config you're using is for webpack v1. I'd advice you to first try making it work with webpack v1 only and once you've a working setup you can migrate to webpack v2/3.

Some changes I can see from the config you've shared to make this work with webpack v2/3 are:

a. Remove the empty string in extensions first.

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  }
}
```

b. Change `loaders` to `rules` and you've to add `-loader` with loader names since automatic `-loader` module name extension is removed, here you've to change `babel` to `babel-loader`.

```
module: {
  rules: [
    { 
       test: /\.jsx?$/,
       exclude: /node_modules/,
       use: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader'],
    },
  ],
},
```

Answer (score 0):

That error is actually pretty helpful
`configuration.resolve has an unknown property 'modulesDirectories'`

Then it tells ya what is available
`These 
    properties are valid:
       object { alias?, aliasFields?, cachePredicate?, cacheWithContext?, 
    descriptionFiles?, enforceExtension?, enforceModuleExtension?, extensions?, 
    fileSystem?, mainFields?, mainFiles?, moduleExtensions?, modules?, plugins?, 
    resolver?, symlinks?, unsafeCache?, useSyncFileSystemCalls? }`

So, your problem is with that pesky

```
modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'bower_components'],
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
```

in your webpack.config.

Go back through your tutorial and see how they've got this in there. Sorry I couldn't be more specific but I hope this helps point you in the right direction. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Couple of changes that worked for me when migrating webpack v1 config to webpack v2/3

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: [
        {loader: 'react-hot-loader'},
        {loader: 'babel-loader'},
      ],
    },
  ],
},

resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
},

resolveLoader: {
    modules: ['node_modules', 'bower_components'],
},
```

More info : 
https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this for several hours I got it to work with the current (webpack 3.8 react 16). By removing my `node_modules` then running

`npm install --save-dev react react-dom webpack webpack-bundle-tracker babel-loader babel-core babel-preset-react babel-preset-es2015`

and my `webpack.config.js` looks like

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');


module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './assets/js/index',
  output: {
      path: path.resolve('./server/static/bundles/'),
      filename: "[name]-[hash].js",
  },

  plugins: [
    new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [{
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
              },
            },
          }],
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    modules: ['node_modules', 'bower_components'],
  },
}
```

and put your `index.jsx` in `./assets/js/index.jsx` with your code

```
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var React = require('react');

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Hope it helps!